# Expanding extensions for todo tasks is throwing 500 error 'expected EntitySet or Singleton'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

GET /users/{Id|userPrincipalName}/todo/lists/{todoTaskListId}/tasks/{Id}?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq '{extensionId}')

is throwing 500 Internal Server Error.

"error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "Expected EntitySet or Singleton"}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am unable to find any documentation on any recent breaking change which is causing this and if any format change is needed in query. Please provide necessary guidance.

This started to happen just recently and there is no documentation online, why such error is getting thrown and how to fix it. I'm using NodeJS for calling this API btw

Comment: I see the same behavior. I will get back with details of fix if available.

Comment: @Danstan hello, any news on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. I have tested and it should be working fine now.

Comment: Thanks! 
Btw, how did this happen? Especially now since the todo API is out of beta. There were no updates that I would find, that would cover this. Should we expect more of these types of issues in the future?